# Simpler, safer string manipulation Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, indexing

I do a lot of amateur data cleaning and scrubbing with Python - it's a lot faster than using Excel.  But I feel like I must be doing everything the hard way.  The biggest pain is that I don't know how to safely get from list indexes or string indexes without getting errors or littering my code with layer after layer of unreadable try/except.

Here's an example of what I just now came up with to clean up Trulia profile URLs for the city/state combo.  Sometimes they don't give a state, but the patterns are pretty standardized.

```
checkstr = 'http://www.trulia.com/profile/agent-name-agent-orlando-fl-24408364/'

state = ''
citystrs = re.findall('-agent-(.*)-\d', checkstr)[0:1]
print citystrs
for citystr in citystrs:
    if '-' in citystr:
        if len(citystr.split('-')[-1]) == 2:
            state = citystr.split('-')[-1].upper().strip()
            city = string.replace(citystr.upper(), state, '')
            city = string.replace(city, '-', ' ').title().strip()
        else:
            city = string.replace(citystr, '-', ' ').title().strip()
    else:
        city = citystr.title().strip()

print city, state
```

I have no need for multiple "answers," but I use the slice [0:1] and `for` because I don't want the error to stop my code (doing this ~2 million times) whenever the pattern doesn't fit for findall[0].

Can I get a few pointers for the pythonic (and efficient) way to do this more simply?

EDIT 1: I'm not looking for nonconforming strings.  I'm hoping to be safe enough to let it run through everything and "do the best it can" (ie, more conforming > less)

EDIT 2: One very obvious detail left out of the example: Cities of multiple words have interior dashes ('-').  E.G. `agent-name-los-angeles-82348233/`

Comment: Can you include a *nonconforming* string?

Comment: i don't understand what the `[0:1]` slice buys you here?  also, `str.partition()` instead of `str.split()` can help, since it always breaks at most once and spits out exactly three substrings.  but since you're using a regex anyway, it seems like you could just express all your possible patterns as regex alternatives?  like `-agent-(?:(\w+)-(\w{2})|...)-\d`

Comment: In the future, if you have working code and just want to improve it, consider taking your question over to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of posting here. It's not necessarily off-topic here so it shouldn't get closed, but reviewing and improving existing, working code is that site's specialty.

Comment: @Eevee - The idea was that I'm avoiding an exception from trying to index [0] on something that doesn't work.  I'm going through millions of lines and I don't trust indexing blindly.

Comment: but you never actually do a `[0]` index anyway.  if `findall` fails it produces an empty list, which the loop will then skip.  you might match more than once per url, but then you can test everything anyway, and `break` when you find a good match

Answer (score 2):

Why not use slices all the way?

```
if '-' in citystr:
    sep_index = citystr.find('-')
    city = citystr[0:sep_index].title()
    state = citystr[sep_index+1:].upper()
else:
    city = citystr.title()
```

Using timeit(number=10000):

```
yours : 3.56353430347
mine :  1.04823075931
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I will do it:

```
import re

reg = re.compile(r'-agent-(?P<city>[^-]*)(?:-(?P<state>[^-]*))?-\d')    

checkstr = 'http://www.trulia.com/profile/agent-name-agent-orlando-fl-24408364/'

m = reg.search(checkstr)

city = m.group('city').title()
state = m.group('state').upper() if (m.group('state')) else ''

print city, state
```

If you need to use the pattern several times, you can compile it once and for all with `re.compile`

Instead of using `.*` that is very permissive and generates backtracking, I use `[^-]*` *(all that is not a dash zero or more times)* that stops before the first dash.

The state and the previous dash are in an optional group: `(?:-(?P<state>[^-]*))?`. So, even if the string doesn't have the state part, the pattern succeeds.

With this change `re.findall` is no more needed, you can use `re.search` that returns a single result. Note that if you are unsure of the string format, you can always add a test to check that there is a match.

To make the code more readable, I use named captures `(?P<name>...)`. So in this way you can easily retrieve the content of a group: `m.group('name')`. However, if you want a little gain of speed, you can use numbered groups (but it isn't very significant).

Comment: I'm sorry - this is an excellent answer, but I did not specify properly that cities can have interior dashes.  That's why I checked the length of the last text bit before a -### part.  I'm even assuming that there are no cities of multiple words (Los Angeles) that end with a two-letter word.  Still, the purpose of my question was to be an example to help me better learn to code more efficiently, and your named grouping helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

- When you are looking for only the first match it would be clearer to use `re.search` instead of `findall`.
- If multiple matches are possible (as suggested by your use of `[0:1]`), note that `.*` is greedy. For example from the string `-agent-orlando-fl-24408364-agent-orlando-fl-24408364` your regex captures `orlando-fl-24408364-agent-orlando-fl`. Use `.*?` instead.
- The `rpartition` string method splits at the last occurrence of the separator and always returns three strings, which makes it easier to deal with corner cases.

Proposed code:

```
m = re.search('-agent-(.*?)-\d', checkstr)
if m:
    citystr = m.group(1)
    city, _, state = citystr.rpartition('-')
    if len(state) <> 2:
        city = citystr
        state = ''
    city = city.replace('-', ' ').title()
    state = state.upper()
```